# Django: Password_reset_complete error

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I'm using django v1.8

In `urls.py` I have

```
url(r'^user/password/reset/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', {'post_reset_redirect' : '/user/password/reset/done/'}, name="password_reset"),
url(r'^user/password/reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done'),
url(r'^user/password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', name='password_reset_confirm'),
url(r'^user/password/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete'),
```

I give my e-mail I get that link:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/password/reset/NA/4c7-8abfc6c9f90cadf94c0f/
```

When I'm trying to reach this link I get `NoReverseMatch at /reset/NA/4c7-8abfc6c9f90cadf94c0f/`

`Reverse for 'password_reset_complete' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead setting different urls in `urls.py` I only set one.

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

Having this, I can use this APIs in browser:

```
accounts/login/ 
accounts/logout/ 
accounts/password_change/
accounts/password_reset/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your `urls.py` from

```
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+) ......
```

to

```
url(r'^user/password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+) ......
```

Comment: Thanks! I did it right know but the problem stills remains.